# Android: Unknown Error-Reason - IllegalStateException

Tags: android, exception, illegalstateexception

I'm programming an app using the AppWarp-SDK for Cloud- and Game-Management-Services.
However, I am getting an error and cannot figure out why.

When I click on my button, the `startClick` method is called and I get the error below in the debugger. Can anyone spot the problem? I tried to figure it out by myself, but couldn't, after 2 hours of trying. I know this is too much code, but I wanted to provide all the necessary information.

```
07-12 18:53:32.206: I/ActivityManager(89): Displayed pack.BAAppWarp42/.GameActivity: +2s383ms
07-12 18:54:08.720: D/AndroidRuntime(1664): Shutting down VM
07-12 18:54:08.720: W/dalvikvm(1664): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3044)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3039)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     ... 11 more
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     at pack.BAAppWarp42.GameActivity.startClick(GameActivity.java:195)
07-12 18:54:12.796: E/AndroidRuntime(1664):     ... 14 more
07-12 18:54:12.916: W/ActivityManager(89):   Force finishing activity pack.BAAppWarp42/.GameActivity
```

There is my sourcecode. Please ignore the rest of it, there are many comments which I have to clean soon.

```
package pack.BAAppWarp42;

import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Timer;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.command.WarpResponseResultCode;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.ChatEvent;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.LiveRoomInfoEvent;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.LobbyData;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.MoveEvent;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.RoomData;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.RoomEvent;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.events.UpdateEvent;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.listener.NotifyListener;
import com.shephertz.app42.gaming.multiplayer.client.listener.RoomRequestListener;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements RoomRequestListener, NotifyListener{

    //Variables
    boolean playing = true;
    boolean online = false;
    int colorGenerator;
    int chosenColor; 
    int targetedColor;
    int startColor;
    static int[][] colorArray;
    static int[][] colorArrayTest;
    String colorString;
    long reactionTime;
    static long start;
    static long end;
    Thread changer;
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    int counter = 0;
    long lastTimeStamp = 0;
    ColorChanger colorChanger = new ColorChanger(this);
    View thisView;
    long latencySent;
    long latencyRespons;
    long latency;
    private int selectedCell = Constants.INVALID_SELECTION;
    private Handler UIThreadHandler;
    private String gameRoomId;
    private JSONObject gameObject;
    private String localUserName;
    private String remoteUserName;
    private int localUserCellImageId;
    private char localUserTile;
    private String currentState;
    private String nextTurn;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private ImageButton selectedButton = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.start);
        colorArray = new int[3][10];

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        localUserName = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.IntentUserName);
        gameRoomId = intent.getStringExtra(Constants.IntentGameRoomId);
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().addRoomRequestListener(this);
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().addNotificationListener(this);

        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().subscribeRoom(gameRoomId);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
    {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }

    public void multiplayerJoinClick (View view) throws InterruptedException{   
    }

    public static JSONObject buildNewGameJSON(String username){
        // prepare the gameObj myself as I'm the one who joined first.
        JSONObject gameObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameFirstUserKey, username);
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameSecondUserKey, "");
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameStateKey, Constants.GameStateIdle);                    
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameBoardKey, Constants.GameEmptyBoard);           
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameWinnerKey, "");
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameNextMoveKey, username);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return gameObject;      
    }

    public void startClick(View view){
        try {
            String boardState = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameBoardKey);
            boardState += "0";
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameBoardKey, boardState);
            AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().setCustomRoomData(gameRoomId, gameObject.toString());
            AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().sendUpdatePeers(Constants.UpdateTrigger);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

//      colorArray = giveColorArray();
//              
//      setContentView(R.layout.game);
//      findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      findViewById(R.id.buttonMid).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      findViewById(R.id.buttonRight).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      findViewById(R.id.winLoseTextfield).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//      
//      findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setBackgroundColor(targetedColor);
//      findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setClickable(false);
//      findViewById(R.id.resetButton).setClickable(false);
//      
//      if(targetedColor == Color.BLACK || targetedColor == Color.BLUE){
//          Button targetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.targetButton);
//          targetButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
//      }
//      
//      Play();
    }    

    public void multiplayerGenerateClick(View view){ 
        colorArray = giveColorArray();
        colorString = colorArrayToString(colorArray);
    }

    private void updateUI()
    {        
        try {
            //this.findViewById(R.id.accountButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            String u1Name = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameFirstUserKey);
            String u2Name = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameSecondUserKey);
            String winner = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameWinnerKey);
            currentState = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameStateKey);
            nextTurn = gameObject.getString(Constants.GameNextMoveKey);
            if(u1Name.equals(localUserName) && u2Name.isEmpty()){
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "waiting for opponent");
            }
            if(u1Name.equalsIgnoreCase(localUserName))
            {
//              localUserCellImageId = R.drawable.cross_cell;
//              localUserTile = Constants.BoardTileCross;
//              remoteUserName = u2Name;
            }
            else
            {
//              localUserCellImageId = R.drawable.circle_cell;
//              localUserTile = Constants.BoardTileCircle;
//              remoteUserName = u1Name;
            }

            //((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit)).setClickable(false);

//          this.drawImagesForBoard(gameObject.getString(Constants.GameBoardKey));  
            if(currentState.equals(Constants.GameStateFinished))
            {               
                if(u2Name.equalsIgnoreCase(localUserName)){
//                  ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.rematch)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                //((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                if(winner.isEmpty())
                {
//                  ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Match Drawn!");
                }
                else if(winner.equalsIgnoreCase(localUserName))
                {
//                  ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("You Won!");
                }
                else
                {
//                  ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("You Lost :(");
                }
            }
            else
            {
//              ((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.rematch)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
//              ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("");
                if(nextTurn.equalsIgnoreCase(localUserName))
                {
//                  ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Your turn against " + remoteUserName);
                    //((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit)).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
//                  ((TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Waiting for "+remoteUserName+" to move");
                    //((Button) this.findViewById(R.id.submit)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }      


    public void startMultiplayerGame(View view) throws InterruptedException{

        setContentView(R.layout.game);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonMid).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonRight).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.winLoseTextfield).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setBackgroundColor(targetedColor);
        findViewById(R.id.targetButton).setClickable(false);
        findViewById(R.id.resetButton).setClickable(false);

        if(targetedColor == Color.BLACK || targetedColor == Color.BLUE){
            Button targetButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.targetButton);
            targetButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        }

        Play();
    }

    private void Play() throws InterruptedException{
        changer = new Thread(new ColorChanger(this));
        changer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        // tell opponent that I am leaving the room
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().leaveRoom(gameRoomId);
    }

    public void onRematchClicked(View view) {
        gameObject = Utilities.buildNewGameJSON(localUserName);
        try {
            gameObject.put(Constants.GameSecondUserKey, remoteUserName);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().setCustomRoomData(gameRoomId, gameObject.toString());
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().sendUpdatePeers(Constants.UpdateTrigger);
    }

    public void leftClick(View view){
        if (ColorChanger.colorLeft == targetedColor){
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            gameWin(view);
        }
        else{
            gameLose(view);
        }
    }

    public void midClick(View view){
        if (ColorChanger.colorMid == targetedColor){
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            gameWin(view);
        }
        else{
            gameLose(view);
        }
    }

    public void rightClick(View view){
        if (ColorChanger.colorRight == targetedColor){
            end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            gameWin(view);
        }
        else{
            gameLose(view);
        }
    }

    private void gameWin(View view){
        reactionTime = end-start;
        ColorChanger.running = false;
        TextView ergebnisfeld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winLoseTextfield);
        ergebnisfeld.setText("Richtig gedrückt. Sehr gut. Reaktionszeit: "+reactionTime+"ms");
        endGame();
    }

    public void gameLose(View view){
        ColorChanger.running = false;
        TextView ergebnisfeld = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winLoseTextfield);
        ergebnisfeld.setText("Falsch gedrückt. Sorry");
        endGame();
    }

    public void endGame(){
        findViewById(R.id.buttonRight).setClickable(false);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonMid).setClickable(false);
        findViewById(R.id.buttonLeft).setClickable(false);
        findViewById(R.id.resetButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.resetButton).setClickable(true);
    }

    public void resetClick(View view){
        finish();       
        startActivity(getIntent());
    }

    public void cancelClick(View view){
        findViewById(R.id.multiplayerButtonGenerate).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.multiplayerButtonJoin).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.gameButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);  
    }

    public void accountClick(View view){

    }

    public void swapButton(View view){

    }

    public void handleOpponentMove(long timestamp, String move){        
        if(findViewById(R.id.cancelButton).getVisibility() == 0){
            findViewById(R.id.pingButton).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            findViewById(R.id.pingButton).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }           
    }

    public void startPing(View view){
        if(!online)
            return;

    }

    private void sendPayload(String payload, long timeStamp)
    {

        latencySent = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public int giveRandomColor(){           
        colorGenerator = (int) (Math.random()*7+1);

        switch (colorGenerator){
            case 1: chosenColor = Color.RED; break;
            case 2: chosenColor = Color.BLUE;  break;
            case 3: chosenColor = Color.YELLOW; break;
            case 4: chosenColor = Color.GREEN; break;
            case 5: chosenColor = Color.MAGENTA; break;
            case 6: chosenColor = Color.GRAY; break;
            case 7: chosenColor = Color.BLACK; break;
            default:chosenColor = targetedColor;
        }

        return chosenColor;
    }

    public int[][] giveColorArray(){
        startColor = (int) (Math.random()*7+1);

        switch (startColor){
            case 1: targetedColor = Color.RED; break;
            case 2: targetedColor = Color.BLUE; break;
            case 3: targetedColor = Color.YELLOW; break;
            case 4: targetedColor = Color.GREEN; break;
            case 5: targetedColor = Color.MAGENTA; break;
            case 6: targetedColor = Color.GRAY; break;
            case 7: targetedColor = Color.BLACK; break;
            default: targetedColor = Color.GREEN;
        }

        int[][] localColorArray = new int[3][10];

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            localColorArray[0][i] = giveRandomColor();  

            do{
                localColorArray[1][i] = giveRandomColor();
            }
            while(localColorArray[0][i] == localColorArray[1][i]);

            do{
                localColorArray[2][i] = giveRandomColor();
            }
            while(localColorArray[0][i] == localColorArray[2][i] || localColorArray[1][i] == localColorArray[2][i]);
        }

        return localColorArray;
    }

    public String colorArrayToString(int[][] array){
        String result = String.valueOf(targetedColor);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            result = result + "," + array[0][i];
            result = result + "," + array[1][i];
            result = result + "," + array[2][i];
        }       

        return result;
    }

    public int[][] colorStringToArray(String string){
        String[] stringArray = string.split(",");
        int[][] resultArray = new int[3][10];
        int arrayCounter = 0;

        targetedColor = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[0]);

        for(int i = 1; i < stringArray.length; i = i + 3){
            resultArray[0][arrayCounter] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i]);
            resultArray[1][arrayCounter] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i+1]);
            resultArray[2][arrayCounter] = Integer.parseInt(stringArray[i+2]);
            arrayCounter++;
        }

        return resultArray;     
    }


    @Override
    public void onChatReceived(ChatEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onMoveCompleted(MoveEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onPrivateChatReceived(String arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onRoomCreated(RoomData arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onRoomDestroyed(RoomData arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdatePeersReceived(UpdateEvent arg0) {
        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().getLiveRoomInfo(gameRoomId); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onUserChangeRoomProperty(RoomData arg0, String arg1,
            Hashtable<String, Object> arg2, Hashtable<String, String> arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUserJoinedLobby(LobbyData arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUserJoinedRoom(final RoomData arg0, final String arg1) {          
                // callback is not the main UI thread. So post message to UI thread
                // through its handler. Android UI elements can't be accessed from
                // non-UI threads.      
                UIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {    
                        if(progressDialog != null ){
                            progressDialog.dismiss(); 
                        }
                        remoteUserName = arg1;
//                      ((TextView) GameActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.status)).setText("Your turn against " + remoteUserName);
                        try {
                            gameObject.put(Constants.GameSecondUserKey, remoteUserName);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }); 
    }


    @Override
    public void onUserLeftLobby(LobbyData arg0, String arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUserLeftRoom(final RoomData arg0, final String arg1) {
        // oh looks like my opponent has left :-(

                // callback is not the main UI thread. So post message to UI thread
                // through its handler. Android UI elements can't be accessed from
                // non-UI threads.
                UIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {      
                        if(arg1.equals(remoteUserName)){                    
                            gameObject = Utilities.buildNewGameJSON(localUserName);
                            AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().setCustomRoomData(gameRoomId, gameObject.toString());
                            GameActivity.this.updateUI();                               
                        }               
                    }
                });


    }


    @Override
    public void onGetLiveRoomInfoDone(final LiveRoomInfoEvent arg0) {   
        if(arg0.getResult() != WarpResponseResultCode.SUCCESS){
            return;
        }

        // callback is not the main UI thread. So post message to UI thread
        // through its handler. Android UI elements can't be accessed from
        // non-UI threads.
        UIThreadHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {      
                try {           
                    String customData = arg0.getCustomData();
                    String roomName = arg0.getData().getName();
                    ((TextView) GameActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.room_info)).setText("Room: " + roomName);

                    if(customData == null || customData.length() == 0){
                        gameObject = Utilities.buildNewGameJSON(localUserName);
                        AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().setCustomRoomData(gameRoomId, gameObject.toString());
                    }
                    else{
                        gameObject = new JSONObject(arg0.getCustomData());
                    }
                    updateUI();
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }               
            }
        });             
    }


    @Override
    public void onJoinRoomDone(RoomEvent arg0) {        

    }


    @Override
    public void onLeaveRoomDone(RoomEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onLockPropertiesDone(byte arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onSetCustomRoomDataDone(LiveRoomInfoEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onSubscribeRoomDone(RoomEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getResult() == WarpResponseResultCode.SUCCESS){
            AsyncApp42ServiceApi.getMyWarpClient().getLiveRoomInfo(gameRoomId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onUnSubscribeRoomDone(RoomEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUnlockPropertiesDone(byte arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdatePropertyDone(LiveRoomInfoEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `IllegalStateException` is caused by a previous `NullPointerException`. Use logcat to see what is happening in more detail. Which piece of code is at the line 195?

Comment: It's the entry of "startClick(View view)"

Comment: I had some problems with IllegalStateException but they were thread problems. I couldn't find the problem in your code but, as I said before, it seems to be with the previous NullPointerException. Put some prints into logcat and try to figure out the problem. Sorry